# I need a field's default create value to to be the current logged in user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm pretty new to Django. I'm working on a ticket system so I'd like users to be able to track the tickets they create. I tried to add CurrentUserDefault to the serializer but I got a very unhelpful 400 error.

Model:

```
class RepairTicket(models.Model):
desc = models.TextField()
createdBy = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='repair_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
resolved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
equipment = models.ForeignKey(Equipment, related_name='equipment', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
operable = models.BooleanField(default=False)
affectsProduction = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return "{} - {}".format(self.desc, self.equipment)
class Meta:
    ordering = ["-created"]
```

Serializer:

```
class RepairTicketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
def to_representation(self, instance):
    representation = super(RepairTicketSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    representation['created'] = instance.created.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
    return representation
class Meta:
    model = RepairTicket
    #fields = ()
    fields = '__all__'
    depth = 1
```

View:

```
class RepairTicketViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = RepairTicket.objects.all()
serializer_class = RepairTicketSerializer
```

Comment: Is there a create attribute in your model? Or do you mean ```createdBy```

Comment: createdBy. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What was the **"response"** of that HTTP 400 response? also, Can you add your view?

Comment: just "Bad Request." Not very helpful. I updated the original post with the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# You have to write create method in the serializer, so that you can get the values and put the value in your database table according to your requirement.

def create(self, validated_data):
    request = self.context["request"]

    desc = request.data.get("desc", None)
    resolved = request.data.get("resolved", None)
    ...

    repair_ticket = RepairTicket.objects.create(
        desc=desc,
        createdBy=request.user,
        resolved=resolved,
        ...
        ...
    )
    return repair_ticket




# Write to_representation in the serializer, so that you can customize the response of the API.

def to_representation(self, instance):
    representation = super(RepairTicketSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    representation['created'] = instance.created.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
    representation['createdBy'] = instance.createdBy.username
    return representation
```